# Is there any odd $n\in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $n=e^2-f^2=g^2-h^2=k^2-l^2$ and $e^2f^2=g^2h^2+k^2l^2$ where $e, f, g, h, k, l~(>1)\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

Is there any odd natural number $n$ satisfying $n=e^2-f^2=g^2-h^2=k^2-l^2$ and $e^2f^2=g^2h^2+k^2l^2$ where $e, f, g, h, k, l~(>1)$ are natural numbers? The problem is related to famous open problem ( around for several centuries) on Pythagorean triples.

Comment: $f=h=l=0$, $n=e=g=k=1$

Comment: 0 is not a natural number

Comment: From... Your wording could be improved by saying "are nonzero integers" or the like, in order to avoid the controversy regarding whether zero is a natural number. [many logicians and some mathematicians view zero as a natural]

Comment: Cross-posted on MathOverflow SE at [Is there any odd natural number $n$ satisfying $n=e^2−f^2=g^2−h^2=k^2−l^2$ and $e^2f^2=g^2h^2+k^2l^2$ where $e,f,g,h,k,l~(>1)$ are natural numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/459418/129887). Note that cross-posting is generally frowned upon, especially if you don't first wait for at least about $7$ days. Also, when you do cross-post, please include a link to the other post, to help avoid things like duplication of effort.

Comment: Note that the restriction $e,f,g,h,k,l >1$ is not necessary, since if there is a solution with some of them $1$ then there is another solution obtained by multiplying each of $e,f,g,h,k,l$ by some odd $k>1$ while also multiplying $n$ by $k^2.$

Comment: The first part is easy where 

$\,\sqrt{n}\in\big\{
24, 36, 40, 48, 56, 60, 64, 72, 80, 84, 88, 96, 100, 
\cdots\big\}$

but the other numbers in the differences are so much different in magnitude that the sum of products equation might never be true.

Comment: @John Omielan: I was not aware of the rule of cross-posting at two different sites with different difficulty level. This problem seems simple, but it actually too difficult. Those who consider it very simple, they can crack it basic mathematics (through math.stackexchange.com). Otherwise, it may be solved with advanced mathematics (through mathoverflow.net). So sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: As I wrote in your fairly new question at [Can we find any odd $n\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $n=e^2−f^2=a(g^2−h^2)=k^2−l^2$ and $e^2f^2=a^2g^2h^2+k^2l^2$ where $a,e,f,g,h,k,l (>1)\in\mathbb{N}$?](/q/4817979), you should never basically repeat a post on the same site.

Answer (score 1):

$(a^2-b^2)=(c^2-d^2)=(e^2-f^2)$

Above has parametric form:

$(a,b,c,d,e,f)$=

$[mn+uv,mn-uv,mu+nv,mu-nv,mv+nu,mv-nu]$ -(1)
We need:

$(ef)^2=(ab)^2-(cd)^2$ ---(2)

Substituting, (1) in (2) we get:
$(m^2n^2+u^2v^2)^2=(m^4+n^4)(u^4+v^4)$

We have numerical solution,

&   $(m,n)^4=(u,v)^4$

$(134,133)^4=(158,59)^4$  --(3)

Hence:
$(m^2n^2+u^2v^2)=(m^4+n^4)$ ---(4)

After substituting, (3) in (4) we find:
$(m^2n^2+u^2v^2)$ is not equal to $(m^4+n^4)$.

Hence in all probability the equation proposed by "OP" does not have a numerical solution.